FFMPEG extract chapters not copying correct title
The original ffmpeg file has the chapters like
Menu
00:00:00.000                             : en:Chapter 01
00:07:02.083                             : en:Chapter 02
00:13:40.833                             : en:Chapter 03
00:23:06.791                             : en:Chapter 04

I extracted the chapters using ffmpeg -i input.mkv -f ffmetadata FFMETADATAFILE.txt. But after extracting the chapters, it appears like below.
Menu
00:00:00.000                             : Chapter 01
00:07:02.083                             : Chapter 02
00:13:40.833                             : Chapter 03
00:23:06.791                             : Chapter 04

the en keyword is missing from the title. any reason why this happens and how to keep the chapters same as how it is in the original file?

Does it work?  If the only language is en, I wouldn't worry, as long as it works.

it works but it removes the en from the title

sed -i 's/\(:[[:space:]]*\)Chapter/\1en:Chapter/g' FFMETADATAFILE.txt will add them back in.

found a solution. not using ffmpeg, but using mkvextract and mkvmerge, which seems to get the job done.
Extract chapters from a file
mkvextract chapters input.mkv > chapters.txt

Add chapters to a file
mkvmerge -o output.mkv --chapters chapters.txt input.mkv

This way the chapter language gets preserved
